# jquery validation with addMethod fails when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, validation

I have an idea this may be stupid, but I've been stuck on it for hours.

I have a simple form, with jquery validation using ajax to determine whether an email address is already in the database.  Works great.  When an email address is found, it reports the duplicate, and when it is not, it is silent.

But when I enter an email I know to be new, and fill out the rest of the form, and press Submit, it prevents the form submission and sets the focus on the email field.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var email;
var name;
var passwd;
var passwd_repeat;

     //form validation rules
     $("#regForm1").validate({
         rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
            },
            passwd: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
            },
            passwd_repeat: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: passwd,
                minlength: 8
            }
         },
         messages:
         {
             name: "Please enter your name.",
             passwd: "Please enter a password.",
             passwd_repeat: "Passwords must match."
         }
     });

    $.validator.addMethod("validateUserEmail", function(value, element) {
        var inputElem = $('#regForm1 :input[name="email"]'),
        data = { "email=" : inputElem.val() },
        eReport = ''; //error report*/
        var dataString = 'email='+ inputElem.val();
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: '/checkdups.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(html) {
                if (html !== 'true') {
                  $('#email').after('<label class="error" for="email">error - '+inputElem.val()+' already in use. Please <a href="http://tester4.com/staff/auth/login">Log in</a> with '+inputElem.val()+'.</label>');
                  return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('ajax loading error... ... '+url + query);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }, 
'');

$(':input[name="email"]').rules("add", { "validateUserEmail" : true} );
```

});

I'm adding a rule with addMethod instead of using .remote because I couldn't get the thing to work more than the first time (meaning it would not reject a succession of dupes without a page refresh), and this was suggested as a workaround.  When I comment the added method out, it allows me to submit the form, but of course does not check for dupes.

Anyway, any insights would be GREATLY appreciated.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use `remote`.  I'm not sure why you weren't getting it to work as you expected - remote definitely **does** get called multiple times.  The way it works by default is to not make a call to the remote page until you hit submit, and then if your remote call says it was bad, every keystroke after that will generate a new remote call.

Here is a [simple working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/yqzDS/) that you can build off of.  I set it up to always return false until you've made 3 changes.  So you should be able to follow these step:

1. Enter john@rand.com and click submit.  Note that it is marked as invalid.
2. delete the m (invalid)
3. delete the o (invalid)
4. delete the c (invalid but due to it not being a valid email address now)
5. type `com` (fixed)
6. submit (works)

The key code from that fiddle is in the rules object (response is a global counter for this example):

```
rules: {
    email: {
        email: true, 
        remote: {
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: function(){
                    response++;
                    return (response > 3)?'true':'false';
                }
            },
            complete: function(data){
                $('#log').append('remote triggered<br>');
            },
            type: 'post'
        },
        required: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ryley, thanks for your reply.  I retried remote and it worked fine. I think I had a problem with a Firefox cache.

Mine looks pretty much like your, so thanks!